# Flask in cPanel showing 404 for images under public folder

Tags: python, flask, cpanel, passenger

I have setup a Flask app in a cPanel server with CloudLinux. I used the Setup Python App feature.

The app is at a folder /home/user/app . The app URL is https://www.example.com/app

cPanel uses Phusion Passenger to make the app work with Apache.

When I created the app, a folder /home/user/app/public was created and supposedly all images should go there.

The app is working well, but all URLs to images in the public folder are giving 404 error. I've tried different urls like https://www.example.com/app/image.jpg, and https://www.example.com/app/public/image.jpg . Always 404.

This is the first time I am using this Setup Python App feature.

Does anyone know which is the right URL to use, or what needs to be configured in order for images to be served?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The image url is created using url_for:

```
return url_for('general.send_data_file', filename=key)
```

The generated url looks correct

I added a route to serve the files:

```
@general_blueprint.route('/public/data_store/data/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def send_data_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config.get('DATA_FOLDER'), filename)
```

I get 404 instead of the file.

The generated file url is /app/public/data_store/data/test.jpg for example. 
The app runs under /app, and all created routes work and don't use the /app when defining the route. I added an app.logger.info call inside the send_data_file, and it is being called.

app.config.get['DATA_FOLDER'] equals ./public/data_store/data

No error in log from send_from_directory .

Comment: Have you tried using the `url_for` as the documentation recommends? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/

Comment: Yes that's how the URL is created. And the url looks correct. But I get 404.

Comment: If you could share a piece of code, it would be nice :)

Comment: I've edited the question and added more information. Thanks.

Comment: You want to serve files, like sending for download or just showing up in a template?

Comment: Just showing the images in an img tag. What I really want is to serve them directly without going through the python app, but passenger is directing the requests to the python app. So I implemented this code to see if I can serve them at least from within the app. But nothing works.

Comment: Ok, firstly I changed the default static folder for Flask. It will only look for files in static folder if that's not changed.

Then you can use url for with the relative path of that folder.

Will send my answer soon with an code example.

Comment: Thanks. These files are uploaded through the website. Is it ok to place them in the static folder?

Comment: That depends, if those files are public, there will be no problem IMO. If they are to be "private", another approach is recommended.

The Flask static folder is meant to serve client based files (js, css, etc.).

That's why I would not serve those files from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serving static files outside your main `static` folder within your app you need to change that in Flask config like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/home/user/app/public')
```

Then, use `url_for` as relative path with `static` as first parameter in your HTML file:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/image.svg') }}" alt="svg image">
```